# Referencing image asset as in-line CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, carrierwave

Calling an image as a background for a div dynamically, based on a stored image via the asset pipeline. Using carrierwave, the call would be

```
  <div class="row imaged-background" style="background:<%= image-url(@staticpage.image_url.to_s) %>">
```

However, this results in:

```
undefined local variable or method `image
```

Taking out `<%=` simply results in `background: image-url(@staticpage.image_url.to_s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this can be of use, this works:

```
background-image: url(<%= @staticpage.image_url.to_s %>)
```

carrierwave appears to be using the rails helpers.